# What does the RC_SIGN_IN means in googleplus login

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin

I need to add login with google plus button to my app. I followed google's documentation in this [Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). But in signin method there is a value called `RC_SIGN_IN`. I do not know what are the values I should assign to `RC_SIGN_IN`.

Comment: Before asking question first read the tutorial carefully. Place where RC_SIGN_IN is used in the link, it gives another link to the complete class of that snippet and there it is defined that RC_SIGN_IN is an integer with value 9000

Comment: 9001! 
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

Comment: @VivekMishra Hopefully he asked the same question that I had. It's not his/her fault, it's a poorly written documentation. Thank you Choxmi !

Comment: @caravana_942 google plus is no longer active so you should probably should not be integrating google plus anymore

Answer (score 52, accepted):

RC_SIGN in is the request code you will assign for starting the new activity. this can be any number. When the user is done with the subsequent activity and returns, the system calls your activity's onActivityResult() method. and that method will be like :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN) {

    }
}
```

For more details you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html).

For your requirement just assign any number to RC_SIGN.