# GoogleApi: Where are permission definitions defined or documented?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to follow code in [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/) and [Google's Sign-in documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn?hl=de). Both refer to the below definitions in a **requestPermissions()** call:

```
RC_DRIVE_PERMS
RC_REQUEST_DRIVE_AND_CONTINUE_FILE_CREATION
```

e.g.

```
GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions( this, RC_DRIVE_PERMS,
              account, Drive.SCOPE_FILE );
```

or

```
requestPermission( Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER, RC_REQUEST_DRIVE_AND_CONTINUE_FILE_CREATION );
```

Where are these defined or documented? Is there a special GoogleAPI/Android forum where questions of this nature should be asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852846/what-does-the-rc-sign-in-means-in-googleplus-login) contains the answer I'm looking for - RC_xxxx values appear to be ID that I need to define myself which are returned back to me within on ActivityResult(). Seems somewhat counter-intuitive for a call such as **requestPermissions()** though.