# Google Sign In for Android: Cannot resolve RC_SIGN_IN

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm trying to authenticate with backend server from mobile app.
I was following this documentation. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
However, there are some errors. `RC_SIGN_IN` and `updateUI()` cannot be resolved.

My code is like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

       GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

       mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent signIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });


   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        updateUI(account);
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}


   private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
       try {
           GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
           String idToken = account.getIdToken();

           // Send Id Token to the backend and validate here

           // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
           updateUI(account);
       } catch (ApiException e) {
           // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
           // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
           Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
           updateUI(null);
       }
   }
```

## Update

Now the button itself doesn't work.

`xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- Include the main content -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Navigation bar -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the mSignInButton of type `SignInButton`

Comment: Yes I set `private SignInButton mSignInButton;`

Comment: Try removing the switch case, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Are you checking on emulator, if yes then you will first have to add a Google account there. Go to the gmail app there and add a Google account there.

Comment: I've removed `switch` statement and already my google account has added on my emulator but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try using it on a real smartphone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the RC\_SIGN\_IN means in googleplus login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852846/what-does-the-rc-sign-in-means-in-googleplus-login)

Comment: you might not be using an emulator image with Play Services enabled, which is a precondition for that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler My emulator enabled Play Services. Still doesn't work even on real device...

Comment: @Wineseller there might be an issue with the Play Services plugin, which might lead to the `google_services.json` not being parsed - then there is no clientId in the string resources and that button will not work... which is the other one precondition.

Comment: @Wine seller Check my Answer,It might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do nothing but replace `RC_SIGN_IN` with an int value. It can be anything but use 1 as it's value. Do as follows:

```
startActivityForResult(signIntent, 1);
```

And change the if code in activity result as follows:

```
if (requestCode == 1)
```

Also change the sign in button click code to this(remove switch cases):

```
mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                      signIn();
               }
           }
       });
```

This is because you are calling on click method to the button and then again checking If the same button is clicked, that's why I think it's not working.

Now for the `updateUI` method, this method should be defined by you. Basically, this is for your app to change what is shown to the user when he/she has signed into the app. If you want to open new activity when `signedIn()` you can use `Intent` by changing the `updateUI(account)` in the activity result and onstart event to an intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

And get which account is signedin in the `SecondActivity`:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.g etLastSignedInAccount(this); //use this in onCreate
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However `sign_in_button` itself doesn't work at all. I tried to set `Toast` inside `OnClickListener` but it doesn't show up.

Comment: Are you getting any null pointer reference or if the app crashes, can you please add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: Also please add where you define the button's Id and initialize it in the code

Comment: The app doesn't crash. The button itself just doesn't work.

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot for helping with patience. I upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`RC_SIGN_IN` is basically an int number code that is used to identify that your onActivityResult is called for google sign-in.

```
 private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;
```

`updateUi()` is method used to let user know that google Signin is successfull or not. Here is method:

```
private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount signedIn) {
  if (signedIn != null) {
      // sigin is successfull
      signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      signOutButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  } else {
      // sigin is cancelled
      signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      signOutButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the errors were fixed. However, `sign_in_button` doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

In MainActivity, implement View.OnClickListener and GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());


private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

        txtName.setText(personName);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .into(imgProfilePic);

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}


private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_sign_in:
            signIn();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_sign_out:
            signOut();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
            revokeAccess();
            break;
    }

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I already tried to implement ViewOnClickListner and override `OnClick` method but still nothing happens.

Comment: I noticed a thing. Only the SignButton doesn't work. I tried with Button for signing in and it works.