# why requestCode in startActivityForResult can be anything

Tags: android, google-oauth

I looked https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity for startActivityForResult and [Google Sign In for Android: Cannot resolve RC_SIGN_IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603331) , but could not find explanation why requestCode can be any value?

Comment: Why can it not be any value?

Comment: I am looking for logic. @commonsware has given that answer, I will leave question open for more input

Comment: The logic can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%2520int,%2520android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1):

In general, if one activity calls `startActivityForResult()` for two or more distinct requests, you will want to use different numeric values for the `requestCode`. Both results will be delivered to the same `onActivityResult()` method implementation, and you use the `requestCode` to distinguish one result from another.

However, beyond that, the values can be whatever you like. So long as your `requestCode` matches between the `startActivityForResult()` calls and your `onActivityResult()` implementation, nothing else cares what the actual number is.

Nowadays, `startActivityForResult()` is still useful between two apps, such as when you use `startActivityForResult()` with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. However, within a single app, usually there are better ways to pass information around. Hence, you will not see as many `startActivityForResult()` calls in modern code as you will in older code.